# c# draw on different layer

Tags: c#, charts, draw, layer

I'd like to make a custom Polar Chart. Therefore I need to draw a Background and the points.

I tried to draw the background and the points on diffrent Panels, but the problem, even if I made the backcolor of the panel transparent I can't see the background(the other panel).

any ideas how I can draw on different transparent layer?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
        panel2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel2_Paint);
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = sender as Panel;
        var g = e.Graphics;

        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Black)), p.DisplayRectangle);

        Point[] points = new Point[4];

        points[0] = new Point(0, 0);
        points[1] = new Point(0, p.Height);
        points[2] = new Point(p.Width, p.Height);
        points[3] = new Point(p.Width, 0);

        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen);

        g.FillPolygon(brush, points);
    }

    private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = sender as Panel;
        var g = e.Graphics;


        g.FillEllipse(myBrush, 10,10,50,50);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just split the drawing code of one panel into several methods, one per layer? This methods can be called from the panels paint event in the correct order.

Comment: I found a solution here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84833/Drawing-multiple-layers-without-flicker  , it's simple and very fast